# How to check Visual Studio 2010 Professional licence key validity

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I bought Visual Studio 2010 Professional from a third party supplier.  I input the key and it all seems to work but when starting up the program it says that it is licensed to 'Microsoft' rather than to me.

How can I check whether the license key I was given upon purchasing Visual Studio 2010 Professional is valid?

Comment: Why did you buy from a third party supplier anyway :/

Comment: because it was far, far cheaper than the Microsoft Shop

Comment: The solution fixed part of the problem, but mostly it was a huge relief to see that Microsoft were aware of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a 64-bit version of Windows? There is a known issue with license information on such systems.

> To resolve this issue we have to follow the steps below. This is a two step process. First the registry needs to modified, this will show the data in Help About dialog box. >Then we have to follow the next set of process to register the values to appear in the 
>   splash screen.
>
> **IMPORTANT Note**: Please ensure you have taken a backup of the registry before making any changes.
>
> Steps for Help About dialog:
>
> **On a x86 bit (32 bit OS) computer follow the below path**:
>
> *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Registration\UserName 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization*
>
> **On a x64 bit (64 bit OS) computer follow the below path**:
>
> *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Registration\UserName 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization*
>
> Changing the **UserName** will change the first line in the help about dialog. 
>   Changing the **RegisteredOrganization** will change the second line in the help about dialog.
>
> Steps to fix the splash screen:
>
> **On a x86 bit**(32 bit OS) computer follow the below path: 
>   *"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup*
>
> **On a x64 bit** (64 bit OS) computer follow the below path: 
>   "*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup*
>
> Launch Visual Studio 2010 to check if both the issues are resolved or not. Also create a new project to 
>   check that the new information is auto populated.

Original link: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/568947/64-visual-studio-2010